# window, console object not accessible in AEM 6.0 Sightly javascript

Tags: aem

I tried to access the javascript basic objects in my AEM 6.0 JS file. But i am getting exception like :
org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: Cannot get DefaultSlingScript: ReferenceError: "window" is not defined.

the js file i am using is

```
use(function () {
    var rets = {};
        var href= window.location.href;
        rets.href= href;
        return rets;
});
```

I am able to access other javascript functions.

Answer (score 2):

[JavaScript Use-API](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/sightly/use-api-in-javascript.html) scripts are executed server-side, not client-side, so you can't access the browser DOM or `window` object.

Comment: Is there any way to pass window object to use api for server rendering?