# Send arguments to use function in JS Use API | AEM 6.5

Tags: javascript, html, api, aem, sightly

I am trying to get the url in my Javascript file. But seems like window.location work in JS Use API neither. So I was trying to send the URL as an argument but that's failing with an error.
My JS code:

```
"use strict";
use(function () {
var url = this.url;
/other code/
});
```

My HTML code:

```
 <sly data-sly-use.item="'myfile.js' @ url=value">
```

Comment: "window.location.href doesn't work" — What does this mean? Does AEM not give you a value for that? Does the value it give you look fine but cause a problem further down?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564059/window-console-object-not-accessible-in-aem-6-0-sightly-javascript    please check this, this is where i found why window wasnt working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTL/Sightly is a server-side template language. The scripts (including JS Use Objects) are compiled and ran once, when the page is rendered. To get the current URL/location you can leverage [SlingHttpServletRequest#getRequestPathInfo](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling11/org/apache/sling/api/SlingHttpServletRequest.html#getRequestPathInfo--). The current request is available as `request` as part of the [HTL Global Objects](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-htl/using/htl/global-objects.html?lang=en).

Also, regarding getting errors when using `<sly data-sly-use.item="'myfile.js' @ url=value">`, that's most probably because `value` is not defined as a variable name in the HTL server-side rendering context. Using `<sly data-sly-use.item="'myfile.js' @ url='https://www.test.com/'">` should work.